# tomlを読み込ませる際に型の融通を聞かせるには

Tags: rust

rustでtomlを読み込ませるには構造体が必要だと聞いたのですが、型に関し融通を聞かせるにはどうしたらいいでしょうか。

```
use serde_derive::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct User {
    user: string   <--数字でもできるようにしたい
}
fn main() {
    let user:User= toml::from_str(r#"
    user=1234
    "#).unwrap()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

TOMLの仕様で整数型と解釈されるので、`"`で囲んでやるべきです。

```
let user: User = toml::from_str(r#"user="1234""#).unwrap();
```

もしくはenumを使って次のように書くこともできます。

```
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum User {
    ByName { user: String },
    ByNumber { user: i32 },
}

fn main() {
    let user1: User = toml::from_str(r#"user=1234"#).unwrap();
    let user2: User = toml::from_str(r#"user="foo""#).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}, {:?}", user1, user2)
}
```

```
ByNumber { user: 1234 }, ByName { user: "foo" }
```

[Enum representations · Serde](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html)